# Factorize column before or after train/test split?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, classification

I'm developing a neural network for a classification problem. I have  a dataset with text id column and I convert the string id into a int id by using pandas.factorize() function.

My text id column which is called 'customer_id' looks like this:

```
      customer_id   
0       Z59FTQD 
1       HMP29SK 
2       VPP29SK
3       VPP29SK 
.. .. .. .. .. 
1500    0JP2FAB
15001   ZJP29AK
```

After I use:

```
dataset['customer_num_id'] = pd.factorize(dataset['customer_id'])[0] + 1
```

to create a new column called 'customer_num_id' to represent the string ids as int values to feed into my neural network model, my new column looks like this:

```
      customer_id  customer_num_id  
0       Z59FTQD      1
1       HMP29SK      2
2       VPP29SK      3
3       VPP29SK      3
.. .. .. .. .. 
1500    0JP2FAB      1500
1501    ZJP29AK      1501
```

I would like to train my model on about 80% of the data and test it on the remaining 20%.

My question is: Should I factorize the dataset before or after I split it into train and test sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encode/factorize it before you split it into testing and training datasets.
This way you ensure consistent factorization in both splits.

Also I would suggestion looking into [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)